# entrySet interface in java

Tags: java

```
// Using entrySet() to get the entry's of the map
// m is previously created Map.

Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> s = m.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> it: s)
{ 
    String str = it.getKey();
 }
```

Map.Enty is just the interface.

An interface doesn't have the implementation of the method `getKey();`

why the code above works? Like how the compiler knows the behavior of `getKey()`?

Comment: Because `Node<K,V>` in `HashMap.java` implements `Map.Entry<K,V>`, so I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: There is an implementation to `Map.Entry` which is being used.  If you step through your code with a debugger, you can probably find out which class, and even step into the source code for that class.

Comment: so you know the word "interface" but apparently you haven't studied why it exists and how it can be used.

Comment: This is polymorphism. There is a difference between the "actual type" and the "apparent type". In short, the code you're reading deals with the apparent one. Any implementer of an interface can be used in such a way.

Comment: And to break your world, interface can implement method since Java 8.

Comment: to " If you step through your code with a debugger, you can probably find out which class " .   Could gdb help me find which class the compiler is using?

Answer (score 0):

As code shown below:

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

This code is from `HashMap`, and if we put a new K-V Entry, the `HashMap` will create a new instance of `HashMap.Entry` :

```
void createEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
    size++;
}
```

So, every `it` variable in your for-each loop is a instance of `HashMap.Entry` **class** which implements `Map.Entry` **interface**.

Comment: Hi, I am still confused. What the dot .  means?  Like Map.Entry?

Comment: Interface Map.Entry<K,V>
All Known Implementing Classes:
AbstractMap.SimpleEntry, AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry   CIted from  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html  this website doesn't mention Entry class implements Map.Entry

Comment: You can find the answer at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: And read the tutorial written by oracle : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html